# Why do i get "the specified blob doesn't exist" only when I try to write to it?

Tags: python, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I am trying to write to a .csv file in an azure container using a notebook in my Synapse workspace. I can read a test file I have placed there:

[image: reading the csv is correct]

However, when I try to write to exactly the same path (with a changed filename) I get the error "HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: The specified blob does not exist."

[image: "The specified blob does not exist " error]

[image: blob doesn't exist error]

The path I am using is:
https://{ACCOUNTNAME}.blob.core.windows.net/{CONTAINER}/{FOLDER}/{FILENAME}.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the storage account syntax : `abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<folder_name>`

I reproduce the same in the environment got this output.

> **Writing CSV files from ADLS.**

**Code:**

```
#write csv file
import pandas
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(
{
'Name':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
'ID':[90, 80, 95, 20]
})

df1.to_csv('abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<folder_name>')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, that worked. To build on this, I found this tutorial useful for saving files more generally to ADLS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-spark-pool-filesystem-spec